# Health Insurance + Salary Calculations

Tags: united-states, california, salary, healthcare, job-offer

Whats a good percentage of my salary to set aside for health insurance in California?

I'm currently looking into a new job which doesn't offer healthcare or dental so I'm trying to figure out how my take home salary would scale to take that into account.

What's a typical Health/Dental plan price per month?

Answer (score 5):

> Whats a good percentage of my salary to set aside for health insurance in California?

**Enough to pay for the plan you enroll in.** It's not really possible (especially for strangers on the internet) to answer more specifically than that.

If you make a lot of money, this may be 5% of your salary. If you make a lot less, it may be 50% or more. If you have low income, you may qualify for additional benefits to help pay for health insurance.

Answer (score 4):

Health insurance cost doesn't scale with salary, so % of salary is not a good measure.

I will advise you to pay attention to all aspects of the plan, including the deductible, HSA eligibility, etc. The plan with the highest premium is not always the best. In fact, the plans with the lowest premium are almost always (in my experience) the cheapest overall except in very specific circumstances, like when you *know* you're going to pay the max out of pocket due to cancer treatments, high-risk pregnancy, etc. I've always received more in HSA funds and saved more in premium than I paid in the deductible and out-of-pocket expenses.